# Python - How to use try/except statement in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, try-catch

I was trying to do this, but It didn't work.  Just to clarify I want value to equal list[0] if it exists.  Thanks.

```
    dictionary = {
    try:
        value : list[0],
    except IndexError:
        value = None
    }
```

Comment: You need to post more surrounding code (what is `list`?)  I think you are confusing a piece of logic that should exist in a function or method somewhere (getting `value`) with the `dict` datatype.  Try posting a complete but very short program, that prints output, and describe what output you expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have to put the `try..exept` *around* the assigment; you cannot put it inside an expression like you did:

```
try:
    dictionary = {value: list[0]}
except IndexError:
    dictionary = {value: None}
```

Alternatively, move the assignment to a separate set of statements:

```
dictionary = {value: None}
try:
    dictionary[value] = list[0]
except IndexError:
    pass
```

or explicitly test for the length of `list` so you can just select `None` with a conditional expression:

```
dictionary = {
    value: list[0] if list else None,
}
```

where the `if list` test is true if the list object is not empty.

You could also use the [`itertools.izip_longest()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) ([`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) in Python 3) to pair up keys and values; it'll neatly cut off at the *shortest sequence*, and fill in `None` values for the missing elements:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
dictionary = dict(izip_longest(('key1', 'key2', 'key3'), list_of_values[:3]))
```

Here, if `list_of_values` does not have 3 values, then their matching keys are set to `None` automatically:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> list_of_values = []
>>> dict(izip_longest(('key1', 'key2', 'key3'), list_of_values[:3]))
{'key3': None, 'key2': None, 'key1': None}
>>> list_of_values = ['foo']
>>> dict(izip_longest(('key1', 'key2', 'key3'), list_of_values[:3]))
{'key3': None, 'key2': None, 'key1': 'foo'}
>>> list_of_values = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> dict(izip_longest(('key1', 'key2', 'key3'), list_of_values[:3]))
{'key3': None, 'key2': 'bar', 'key1': 'foo'}
>>> list_of_values = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> dict(izip_longest(('key1', 'key2', 'key3'), list_of_values[:3]))
{'key3': 'baz', 'key2': 'bar', 'key1': 'foo'}
```

Comment: I see, thanks.  Is there a more efficient way to do this say if I'm checking multiple list elements?

Comment: @PiccolMan: are we talking about extracting the first element for all of those, or is this for different indices from the same list?

Comment: The third part "if list else None" works excellently for my case.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the 'in' keyword to see if something exists as a key in a dictionary

```
if list[0] in dictionary:
    value = list[0]
else:
    value = None
```

Just a note, avoid using 'list' as a variable name.

Here's what you're trying to do I'm assuming:

```
new_dictionary = dict()
if list[0] in dictionary:
    new_dictionary['value'] = list[0]
else:
    new_dictioanry['value'] = None
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was clear enough, I don't want to check if list[0] is in dictionary.  I want to check if there is even an index of 0 for list, and if so, then make value = list[0].  And thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Oh, in that case you could check if the length of the list is greater than or equal to 1.  `if len(list) >= 1: do what you need to do`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have fixed my problem.